# TranslateAnimation over SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, translate-animation, supportmapfragment

Hi I'm trying to slide up a `RelativeLayout` over a `SupportMapFragment`. Something like this:

[image]

When I click in the marker the `RelativeLayout` slides up. My problem is that as we all know, the SupportMapFragments relies in the `SurfaceView` so any animation that I do over the `SupportMapFragment` isn't shown until the view gets invalidated, for example, when I click the pause button. I can't show you the code because is in my job pc's. But theres nothing from another world. Just a plain and simple `TranslateAnimation` that I load with `AnimationUtils.load(context,resource)`. I even test the animation in another fragments and work well. Well, my question is: There's some workaround for this kind of problem, maybe wrap the `SupportMapFragment` inside another view or something like that?

Any tip is welcome!

**UPDATE:**
Basically in the xml I have the `SupportMapFragment` and the `RelativeLayout`. In the code I take the `RelativeLayout` with the `findViewById` then I load the animation with `AnimationUtils` I set the animation to the `RelativeLayout` with the `setAnimation` method and later I start the animation. Seems work pretty well in another fragments, I doubt that the problem is here.

Comment: You can try the solution posted in here: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/168, with the method `setMapTransparent`